# Can't search any non-English [Unicode] using html form on flask app

Tags: python, mysql, database, flask, unicode

I have 4 data table created with sqlalchemy + mysql.

2 is with English data and other 2 with Bangla[unicode] data. Everything is working fine when i search from my html form and showing the result from every table on my local computer.

after deploying on a cPanel based shared hosting non-English data not showing anymore. [ if i create loop every data shows but not showing any filter data when i search after hosting.

even when i use non-English url it's not working on production server. but in local computer works fine.

I don't know whats the porblem.

here all the code

app.py:

```
    from flask import Flask, render_template, abort, session, redirect, request,url_for,make_response
    from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
    from datetime import datetime,timedelta
    from flask_admin import Admin
    from flask_admin.contrib.sqla import ModelView
    import sqlalchemy
    
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = "mysql+pymysql://usernameisok:passwordisok@localhost/sobdarth_sobdartho"
    app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = "tanvir.comahmedoke"
    app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False
    db = SQLAlchemy(app)
    admin = Admin(app)
```

Model:
**This tables data not showing anything when i search but other English table works fine.**

```
 class BanglaBangla(db.Model):
        word_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
        bn_word = db.Column(db.String(70), nullable=False)
        word_type = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=True)
        core_meaning = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=True)
        bn_definition = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=True)
        next = db.Column(db.String(70), nullable=True)
        prev = db.Column(db.String(70), nullable=True)
    
        def __repr__(self):
            return f'<bn_to_bn id: {self.word_id}, word: {self.bn_word}>'
```

Routing:

```
    @app.route("/bangla-to-bangla/")
    def bn2bn():
        try:
            word1 = request.args.get('bangla2bangla')
            return redirect(url_for('bn2bn_result', bn_word=word1))
        except:
            return render_template('files/bn2bn/bn2bn404.html')
    
    
    @app.route("/bangla-to-bangla/<bn_word>")
    def bn2bn_result(bn_word):
        try:
            bangla = BanglaBangla.query.filter_by(bn_word=bn_word).one()
            return render_template('files/bn2bn/bn2bn.html', bn_word=bangla)
        except:
            return render_template("files/bn2bn/bn2bn404.html")
```

Templates:

```
              <form method="get" action="/bangla-to-bangla/">
              <input type="text" name="bangla" id="bangla" {% if bn_word.bn_word == None %} placeholder="Type Word..."{% else %} value="{{ bn_word.bn_word }}" {% endif %}>

              <button>Search</button>
              </form>



            <div class="meaning outputs" >
                <h1>{{ bn_word.bn_word }} Meaning In Bangla</h1>
                <p><b>{{ bn_word.core_meaning }}</b> ({{ bn_word.word_type }})</p>
            </div>
```

this is how i started my app with requirements.txt :

[Click to check the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fGtxw.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try to contact with your hosting provider maybe.
Not Sure Whats the problem. hope someone help you.